# Carrier Billing in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement Carrier Billing payment mode for my iPhone app but could not find much references on it. Can anyone who worked the same redirect me to any Carrier Billing providers or any libraries/SDK which helps me?

Thanks in advance,
Vasu

Comment: I don't know what this question means. Provide some links and some example code to show what you have tried.

Comment: Carrier billing is when you make a purchase on a phone and it shows up in your cell phone bill- it's billed to your cell phone carrier.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have carrier billing in an iPhone app destined for the AppStore.  It is against the guidelines

[AppStore Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies)

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks a lot for your reply. After some R&D I found a Carrier billing provider called Zebbo (http://zebbo.com). They say that its supported for iPhone, Android and BB. I am looking at its feasibility.

Comment: What would you like to use carrier billing for?  And it looks like Zebbo is primarily for use on mobile web, not native apps.

Comment: Basically my app allows user to purchase some products. I am thinking to do it via Carrier Billing instead of In-App Purchase any other payment gateway services (like Paypal), because it looks simple (as per my knowledge) from user perspective. He doesn't need use the Credit card or any other stuff to purchase a product. Just his phone is enough. Please let me know ur thoughts.

Comment: If it's for purchasing a physical good, you're not allowed to use in app purchase, so you'd have to use something third-party like paypal, carrier billing or another credit card processor.

Comment: This should be interesting :http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/27/9620712/apple-carrier-billing-o2-germany